# Does Collections.sort() shuffles equal priority elements?

Tags: java, sorting

Or just let them alone or throws an exception?

If the third one, how can I sort elements in ArrayList saving the old order of priority equal elements?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`Collections#sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) is a stable sorting algorithm, so it won't shuffle the equal priority elements. The only way `Collections#sort` throws an error is that you send an unmodifiable list

Comment: or a broken implementation of compareTo !

Comment: @Affe How would you define a "broken implementation of `compareTo`"?

Comment: One that does not obey the rules specified here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)
?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference now but I don't know why so many people closed it. It "demonstrates a minimal understanding of the problem being solved" and doesn't have any code because the problem is quite abstract - everything needed is written.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29):

> This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.

To save the order of the old arraylist, simply make a copy of the arraylist ahead of time.  You can do this by saying:

```
List<Integer> oldListOrder = new ArrayList<Integer>(listToBeSorted);
Collections.sort(listToBeSorted);
```

Keep in mind the elements will reference the same objects in both lists.  That may not affect you, it depends on what you do next.

Comment: By saying old order I meant the old order between the same priority elements, not a new List. But what you said in beginning was exactly what I wanted.